# Matching group in node.js regex string parameter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

The `String.prototype.replace()` [method documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) says:

> ### Specifying a string as a parameter
>
> The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns:
>
> - `$$`: Inserts a "$".
> - `$&`: Inserts the matched substring.
> - `` $` ``: Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.
> - `$'`: Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
> - **`$n`:     Where `n` is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the *n*th parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a `RegExp` object. Note that this is 1-indexed.**

The browser compatibility section also indicates that Node.js supports the `String.replace` command.

However, I have tried the following in Node.js:

```
> 'lalalalalalalffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$1")
'lalalalalalalffffff'
> 'lalalalalalalffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$2")
'lalalalalalalffffff'
> 'lalalalalalalffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$3")
'lalalalalalalffffff'
```

I would expect the responses to be `la`, `la`, and `ffffff` respectively. What isn't working here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your example shows, your sample input is `lalalalalalalffffff`, but note the `l` before the first `f`. The problem is that your regex matches nothing, because it can't find one-or-more `la`s followed by an `f`, because of that silly `l`.

You can see for yourself at **[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/m7KeKt/1)**

If you do want to keep the extra `l`, and have `$2` give an output of `la`, you can try:

```
(la)(la[l]?)*(f.*)
```

**[over here](https://regex101.com/r/m7KeKt/2)**.

---

And, if you want `$2` to match `lalalalalal`, you can use:

```
(la)((?:la[l]?)*)(f.*)
```

Which will also match `lalala` for `lalalalafffffff`

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because your regex is not matching your string (which is probably wrong).

You're missing an `a` after the last `l`, or you have to drop the last `l`

`lalalalalalalffffff` => `lalalalalalalaffffff`

```js
console.log('lalalalalalalaffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$1"));
console.log('lalalalalalalaffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$2"));
console.log('lalalalalalalaffffff'.replace(/(la)(la)*(f.*)/, "$3"));
```